# How do I install npm on an Azure instance of Ubuntu (14.10)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, azure

I tried using `sudo apt-get install npm` but it bails with

http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_3.16.0-30.40_amd64.deb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created a new Ubuntu 14.10 vm on Azure and used the cmd below:

```
$sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

Install was successful. Try apt-get update or check your sources in case you made modifications to it.